# Deserializing token field from oauth2 JDBCTokenStore

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-security-oauth2

I've used the [JDBCTokenStore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.java)as my primary Token store for my oauth2 authentication tokens. Normally, when the request is coming through our Spring Java application we can easily parse the token to it's access_token string form since we're using Spring.

The problem lies when the oauth access token token field is being accessed by another application. They can't seem to translate the BLOB/bytea token field  into String and used the string to be compared on their side.

So here's the access token store as bytea token

[image]

and here's the access_token that came from our spring java app

[image]

How do we convert the bytea token to it's string form from Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it wrong. The token_id is the actual access_token that spring oauth2 config creates. Before it stores the token_id on your persistent storage(e.g Postgresql) the generated token_id is digested through MD5. Which can be found here.

You can always use [encode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-binarystring.html) from postgresql. However I highly doubt that you can easily parse

if you want other applications to translate/decode it back to its regular string form. You'll have to use this.

```
   String token_id =  "ceb589c0-8a01-4513-96d9-6ed10d6f8c77";

        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("MD5 algorithm not available.  Fatal (should be in the JDK).");
        }

        try {
            byte[] bytes = digest.digest(token_id.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, bytes))) ;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("UTF-8 encoding not available.  Fatal (should be in the JDK).");
        }
```

That being said. You must let the other application use that some sort of approach in order for you to translate it back to the access_token you have received from Spring oauth2